# Spark libraries conflect when cosmosdb Lib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, azure-cosmosdb

I keep getting a spark library conflict with cosmosdb libraries and unable to resolve it.   Please help???

build.sbt

```
name := "myApp"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.3.0",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.3.0" ,
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.3.0" ,
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.3.0" ,
"com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-storage" % "2.0.0",
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-azure" % "2.7.3",
"com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11" % "1.0.0",
"com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-documentdb" % "1.14.2" ,
"com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-documentdb-rx" % "0.9.0-rc2" ,
"io.reactivex" % "rxjava" % "1.3.0" ,
"io.reactivex" % "rxnetty" % "0.4.20",
"org.json" % "json" % "20140107",
"org.jmockit" % "jmockit" % "1.34" % "test"
)
```

The compilation errors I'm getting are:

```
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in 
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-launcher _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-ast _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.twitter:chill _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-jackson _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-core _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-core _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-network-common _2.11, _2.10
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.apache.spark:spark-launcher, org.json4s:json4s-ast, org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle, com.twitter:chill, org.json4s:json4s-jackson, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala, org.json4s:json4s-core, org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-core, org.apache.spark:spark-network-common
```

Thanks

Comment: Did the answer work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across this issue. You probably have to use Scala 2.10 with the above inorder to avoid conflict.

Comment: Thanks and that resolve the issue.  I wish that was stated in the document.  I actually looked into CosmosDB Spark connector code which caused the conflict and it looks that it leveraged scala 2.11 which add to the confusion.